# What is an easy way to Localize a SQL Server Reporting Services report (.rdl)?

Tags: reporting-services, localization

I am trying to provide a Spanish and English version of the reports that I am currently building in SQL Server Reporting Services. Is there an easy way to localize the report (similar to using Resource files for labels in a .NET web application)?

Comment: +1 same here... just been putting off the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all just .Net code so you could access standard resource file via some helper methods in a custom assembly, but this gets hard to test etc

An example of this is here http://forums.asp.net/p/952617/1171729.aspx

Sometimes a simpler soulution is to have a language table in your database and have all lables use a filter on it by label name and the User!Langauge parameter

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can see the post below if that helps you.

http://bharatsavaliya.blogspot.com/2009/06/custom-functionscode-in-sql-reporting.html

Regards,
B